# Flow Type Ignore all 3rd party libraries

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

We are basically migrating away from flow type and dont want to maintain and/or rely on any 3rd party types/resolutions anymore. We are okay with all those modules being `any` and we dont want to use flow-typed anymore.

Our current config is:

```
[include]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/app/src/client
[ignore]
  .*\.json
  .*\.spec\.js
  .*\.test\.js
[options]
module.system.node.allow_root_relative=true
module.system.node.root_relative_dirname=<PROJECT_ROOT>/app/src/client
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules
[version]
  0.134.0
```

Which gives us a ton of errors within node_modules itself and inside the 'src' code no 3rd party module can be resolved - e.g.: "Cannot resolve module 'ramda'".

We tried various [declarations] and [untyped] options with no success.

The directory structure is:

```
/packages
  .flowconfig
  /app
    /src
      /client
```

So to sum up we want:

- node_modules to be resolved (no error in app code when importing)
- node modules to be `any`
- no type checking within node_modules

Comment: I'm curious about why? It would be helpful to know what limitations you're facing so the system can improve.

Comment: Its mostly about third party type support and community support. TS seems more widley adopted and the "Googlebility" (examples, tutorials, bug fixes etc.) is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible using `[untyped]` section in a `.flowconfig`

> The `[untyped]` section in a `.flowconfig` file tells Flow to not typecheck files matching the specified regular expressions and instead throw away types and treat modules as `any`.

```
[untyped]
.*/node_modules/.*
```

[Docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/untyped/)

Comment: That partly works I guess. Modules from node_modules are still unresolved.

Comment: Can you share a sample repo? Just tested and it works as expected

Comment: I marked it as accepted answer as its working for probably most use cases. we had other issues that were probably related to our custom setup. We now opted for [untyped] and manually stubbing the rest via flow-typed (although it wouldve been nice to get rid of flow-typed all together...)